# MS Word, allow a word in the middle of a sentence to have capitalized first letter

Tags: microsoft-word

More details about my question:

As shown in the above screen capture, I think paragraph 1 and 2 had the same formatting, but why "**The**" had an indication that needs to be decapitalized?

I want something like paragraph 1,

A word with capitalized first letter in the middle of a sentence (after the heading), but without error indication.

[image: Screen Capture]
[(bigger image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvyUf.png)

=== Update 1 ===

In my document, there are a lot of green indications like this one, the right-lick menu suggestion is to decapitalize the first letter. So I think these are more formatting issue rather than grammar issue.

I could 'Ignore' the indication, but I don't want the greens show again when somebody else opens the doc.

=== Update 2 ===
The 'small circle' showed in the above doc was because I turned on the option "show the paragraph markers and other hidden formatting symbols". It is a "Nonbreaking space".

This the document with normal view.

[image]
[(bigger image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wQTv.png)

=== Update 3 with the question closure ===

**Thanks for all the answers and help.**

At the moment, I still have the green line indication, but I think I know the reason of it. At the beginning, I thought it was a formatting issue, as there are first letter capitalized word in the middle of 
both paragraphs, and paragraph 1 doesn't have the green line. It makes me think that WORD might have a setting that allow the situation in paragraph 2, under the normal grammar & formatting checking rule. Because even if I turned off (or 'ignore') the checking indication, other people will still see it when they open the doc in their word.

Later of that, I tried different words at the highlighted area, and only some word combination didn't give the 'green line'. So I think it's a grammar issue, and there is no way to top WORD give the green line indication for this situation unless turn the checking off or 'ignore' it.

Comment: Sadly, a few people are editing the doc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to know why Word thinks certain rules need to be applied in certain situations like this. The two highlighted words start different parts of speech. One is a noun ("The human genome sequence data") and the other starts a preposition ("In order to simulate ribo-seq data"), so it's not unexpected that Word will treat them differently. English is a very complex language, and Word frequently misinterprets input data when trying to apply grammar rules.

If you want to make the error indicator go away in paragraph 2, hover over the "The" and select "Ignore" from the popup.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I think this is more formatting than grammar issue. I have updated my post for this point.

Comment: While I think you're correct, I believe Word counts capitalization issues under its grammar rules :) Have you tried ignoring it and seeing if it stays ignored for others that you give the document to? I think you can even tell it to "Ignore All" to suppress it for the entire document instead of just one instance.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that small circle character you are using is considered as a period.  Not in the english language but in Japanese.  So Word would be correct in suggesting capitalization (just not in your language of choice).

This should help make word less annoying:
http://www.techrepublic.com/article/disable-autocorrects-automatic-capitalization-in-word/

Comment: Word is wanting to lower-case the second paragraph, not capitalize it.

Answer (score 1):

I only want to suggest that Word may be interpreting your non-breaking space as adjoining other, regular spaces. Since it is irregular to use two spaces in a row, Word simply thinks you are starting a new sentence, and thus it is capitalizing the first word.